# can not import nvidia_smi

Tags: python, nvidia

I'm tending to collect my GPU status during my python code is running.
I need to `import nvidia_smi` in my code to do this.
but even by installing it by `pip install nvidia_smi` hit this error:
`No module named 'nvidia_smi'`

Any Idea?

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer [here](https://forums.fast.ai/t/show-gpu-utilization-metrics-inside-training-loop-without-subprocess-call/26594)
just `pip install nvidia-ml-py3`:

and:

```
import nvidia_smi

nvidia_smi.nvmlInit()
handle = nvidia_smi.nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(0)
```